# using an xml file to initialise javascript program

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing

I'm writing a game that uses an xml file as starting values for map,player etc. .
I'd like an easy way to initialise the game from an xml file.
my xml is:

```
<save>
  <player>
    <name> "martin" </name>
    <coins> 100 </coins>
    <hp> 15 </hp>
  </player>
  <map>
    <height> 5 </height>
    <width> 5 </width>
  </map>
</save>
```

and I want the javascript code output (to the top of my game file)

```
var player = {
    name:"martin";
    coins:100;
    hp:15;
}
var map = [[[],[],[],[],[]],
[[],[],[],[],[]],
[[],[],[],[],[]],
[[],[],[],[],[]],
[[],[],[],[],[]] // although not formatted this way
```

so basicaly I want to load data, from xml, into objects and arrays.
then I can do things such as changing the player's hp using javascript's built in functions.
thanks,
martin

Comment: Is this game hosted on a server or local?

Comment: Also, I'd suggest that you use JSON rather than XML, because JSON is designed specifically for JavaScript.

Comment: it's local, but could be hosted...

Comment: Ok, are you on Windows on OS X/Linux btw?

Comment: Linux. I find it the best for development.

Comment: then you can do it with AJAX and run a Python server (`cd path/to/directory && python3 -m http.server`) to allow it to work without putting it on a real server. AJAX won't work locally.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this with [JSON](http://json.org/) is much easier. You can use [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX) to load the JSON file and set the value; here's an example.

JavaScript file (e.g. `script.js`):

```
var player = {
  name: "martin",
  coins: 100,
  hp: 15
}

var map =
[[[], [], [], [], []],
 [[], [], [], [], []],
 [[], [], [], [], []],
 [[], [], [], [], []],
 [[], [], [], [], []]];

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.onstatechange = function () {
  var data;
  if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
    data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    player = data.player;
    map = data.map;
  }
}

request.open("GET", "data.json");
request.send();
```

JSON data (e.g. `data.json`):

```
{
  "player": {
    "name": "martin",
    "coins": 100,
    "hp": 15
  },

  "map":
  [[[], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], []]]
}
```

For this you'll need to be running your code on a server, which you can do with Python if you're developing locally:

```
$ cd path/to/directory
$ python3 -m http.server
```

Then just open the IP address (with the correct port) in your web browser.